# Is it possible to make this search function remove the answers when a new search is submitted?

Tags: javascript, json, api, search

Is it possible to make this search function remove the previous answers every time a new search is submitted?

http://www.urlgone.com/acfdd9/

(Preview does not seem to work, try running the files locally perhaps, it works locally for me)

Comment: Anyone? I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: `#include "telepathy.h"`

Comment: `https://c9.io/folly/javascript_search_function` show nothing ?

Comment: `Cannot GET /folly/javascript_search_function`

Comment: If it's about javascript, just make a JSFiddle